# To use Android Studio encountered an error

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have Android Studio (Google I/O Preview).
I created an android project in Android Studio, and when I run it, the Studio tell me :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7534 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/username/android-studio/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/username/android-studio/lib/idea_rt.jar:/home/username/android-studio/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/home/username/android-studio/sdk/platforms/android-17/android.jar:/home/username/android-studio/sdk/platforms/android-17/data/res:/home/username/android-studio/sdk/tools/support/annotations.jar:/home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/test/test/libs/android-support-v4.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 @/tmp/idea_junit6666593680737984739.tmp -socket52225
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.textui.ResultPrinter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 3 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What can I try?I've Googled this but haven't had much luck.

Comment: Do you have JUnit lib in project dependencies?

Comment: I don't know.When I use the Windows Version, I didn't meet any error; and when I use the Linux Version, I created the same project, it occurs the errors.

Comment: I am a beginner and my English is poor , I hope you can understand what I said.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231639/unable-to-run-simple-junit-testcase-on-old-version-of-junit

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know.When I use the Windows Version, I didn't meet any error;

Sounds like to me from your windows version has the missing class while your Linux Version does not.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.textui.ResultPrinter

Make sure you have this class in your library or where ever you are calling it for.

Hope this helps or points you to the right direction.

Comment: I don't know why.Too strange !