# Android classes in Java project

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing

I'd like to write unit tests for classes of an Android application. I found that it is faster to run the test cases on my PC. I created a separate Java project and put my classes and test cases into that project. The packages of this project is used from my Android application.

This works for my classes that  don't use Android classes. Is there a way to use the classes of the Android Library in this project? So that I could run the unit tests on my PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include android.jar from the SDK in your classpath.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422378/intellij-idea-with-junit-4-7-junit-version-3-8-or-later-expected