# Android Junit - "Class not found"

Tags: java, android, junit

For my Android project I'd like to test pure Java code. To achieve this, I want to use JUnit.

Due to known bug:

```
!!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.<init>(BaseTestRunner.java:5)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:54)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:48)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:41)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.junitVersionChecks(JUnitStarter.java:190)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.canWorkWithJUnitVersion(JUnitStarter.java:173)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I installed proper plugin to Android Studio and added:

```
classpath 'com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:2.1.1'
```

and in app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android-unit-test'

dependencies {
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.11')
}
```

As JUnit was added I wrote simple test class in src/androidTest/java/com.adamstyrc.mytrack.unit:

```
package com.adamstyrc.mytrack.unit;


import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class SimpleTest extends TestCase {

    public void testName() {
        assertEquals(7, 6);
    }
}
```

But what I get is:

```
Class not found: "com.adamstyrc.mytrack.unit.SimpleTest"
```

Why is it not visible ?

Comment: check [this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422378/intellij-idea-with-junit-4-7-junit-version-3-8-or-later-expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, as https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test says the path has to be:

> src/**test**/...

instead of src/androidTest/

and nothing like:

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        setRoot('src/androidTest') 
    }
}
```

can change it.