# !!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected

Tags: java, android, junit

My Android studio project has an app module which is android framework dependent, I have created a new module called domain and  it contains only pure java classes and a few test classes.

In this module's build.gradle file, I have added junit and mockito libraries for testing purpose as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    compile project(':common')
    compile project(':model')
    //test dependencies
}
```

But Android Studio is giving me `!!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected` error message whenever I try to execute the test class.

All the suggested solutions to this problem is to open the Project Structure | Modules | Dependencies, and move the junit-4.7.jar up, so that it comes before Android 1.6 Platform in the classpath.

In fact, I have tried to implement this solution but the problem still exists.
[image: Image of my dependencies structure]

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What does your Run/Debug Configuration look like for your tests? Specifically, what does the property "Use classpath of module" say for your tests? You can find this on _Run_ -> _Edit Configurations_, then select a configuration on the left.

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: I could solve it by removing `unitTest.returnDefaultValues`, check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44820309/965569

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by by changing the following in .iml file

from:

```
 <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
```

to:

```
  <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. These are different tags. <orderEntry> goes inside <component>.

Comment: This is not a good practice as the end-user of your project can import your project and Intellij will recreate the *.iml file.

Comment: Found on my side that the problem is cached references for older dependencies and in this case this solution is leading other fellow developers to anti-patterns, this is especially bad if the developer starts his journey following posts like this. Do not modify the *.iml, its somewhere in the official Intellij documentation

Answer (score 51):

I've already solved this just now. It may help you... maybe.
A little instruction:

1. Go to Run -> Edit Configurations
2. Delete JUnit configuration on left panel

[image]

Comment: It works for me. Probably it clean undesirable cache.

Comment: But after you delete the Unnamed JUnit config, what do you run for (J)Unit Test?

Comment: That worked for me, seems to be common when you use android and both unit tests.

Comment: Didnt work for me and now I don't know how to restore my Unit test configuration

Comment: @J.K. that's what i was worried about. Did you ever figure out how to have both instrumentation tests and unit tests?

Comment: @SteveG this is how I restored my configuration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068170/how-to-restore-a-deleted-runconfiguration-in-android-studio

Comment: Thank you, it works for me building kotlin in IDEA

Comment: Worked for me as well!

Comment: Worked for me thanks.

Comment: It may also be worth to check your classpath and workdir set for the test in IDEA, it does not get it always right on tis own, at least for gradle projects.

Answer (score 8):

I've managed to solve it with simply editing the project's iml and moving order enrty for junit , in my case:

```
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="TEST" name="junit-4.13-SNAPSHOT" level="project" />
```

up to be the first orderEntry after `</content>`

Comment: Din't fix the problem for me.

Comment: @Rotem Slootzky Thanks for the fix! Any bug tickets you can point us to? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had this but the reason was different..I had inadvertently set my build variant to Release and didn't have any signing info specified so nothing could be built and run on the device.

The cryptic error it gave me was this same one when I tried running the integration tests...didn't notice the app was also disabled :-P
Set it back to Debug and it worked fine.