# How to restore a deleted RunConfiguration in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to deal with a testing-related problem and I followed this advice:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32267762/2576903

Now whenever I try to run my tests, I get prompted to choose a device.
How do I restore that build configuration?

I tried git commit to see changed files, but it seems that it was somewhere outside of the project folder. I also tried invalidating android studio's caches but nothing seems to work.

I tried creating another test class automatically (by control + enter on the name of a regular POJO) but the configuration wasnt created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went to the folder of my current test class, 
created a new class
inserted annotation `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitTestRunner.class)`

right clicked the newly created class' name -> `Run`
and it created the configuration.