# Android Studio 3.0 "JUnit version 3.8 or later expected"

Tags: java, android, junit, kotlin

tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172698/junit-version-3-8-or-later-expected) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422378/intellij-idea-with-junit-4-7-junit-version-3-8-or-later-expected) but without any luck.

I am using Android studio 3.0 and junit 4.12. Windows 10.

What I have tried:

1. move the junit dependency up (tried test compilation and implementation scope)
   [image]
2. delete the tests in Run - Edit configurations... - remove all under Android JUnit and Android App
   [image]

---

---

**My graddle looks like this:**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':domain')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompileOnly 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.1.0'
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'org.amshove.kluent:kluent:1.14'
    implementation 'com.google.api.client:google-api-client-repackaged-com-google-common-base:1.2.3-alpha'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
}
```

**My test looks like this:**

```
package ***.roompanel.data;

import com.google.gson.FieldNamingStrategy;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import ***.roompanel.data.RestApi.ApiFieldNamingStrategy;
import ***.roompanel.data.RestApi.ApiGsonBuilder;
import ***.roompanel.data.RestApi.ApiItemTypeAdapterFactory;
import ***.roompanel.data.RestApi.ApiService;
import ***.roompanel.data.RestApi.IApiService;
import ***.roompanel.data.repository.EventRepository;
import ***.roompanel.domain.model.event.Event;
import ***.roompanel.domain.repository.IEventRepository;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;


public class EventRepositoryTest {
    IEventRepository repo;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        TypeAdapterFactory typeAdatperFactory = new ApiItemTypeAdapterFactory(); // system to
        FieldNamingStrategy fieldNamingStrategy = new ApiFieldNamingStrategy();
        Gson gson = new ApiGsonBuilder(typeAdatperFactory, fieldNamingStrategy).build();

        IApiService service = new ApiService(gson);
        this.repo = new EventRepository(service);
    }

    @Test
    public void events_void_success() throws Exception {
        Date start = new Date(2017,10,01);
        Date end = new Date(2017,10,12);

        List<Event> events = (List<Event>) repo.load(start, end);

        assertNotNull(events);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

**./gradlew test**

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 25s
53 actionable tasks: 30 executed, 23 up-to-date

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.<init>(BaseTestRunner.java:5)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:54)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:48)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:41)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.junitVersionChecks(JUnitStarter.java:224)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.canWorkWithJUnitVersion(JUnitStarter.java:207)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

Comment: change  testCompileOnly to testImplementation

Comment: as stated in What I have tried - didn't help

Comment: Try running `./gradlew test` from the terminal....

Comment: edited my question with the output of gradlew @tynn

Comment: Can try: "Go to Run -> Edit Configurations" and delete all "Android Junit" configurations?

Comment: Hi, as stated in "what I have tried 2. point" I have already done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the solution, just a messy workaround (since it took too much time to solve it):

> Uninstall and install the android studio 3.0 again. Do not update the
>   kotlin plugin and the android studio to newer versions.