# Android Studio - with Junit 4.12 “!!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:”

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit

Tried out the suggestions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422378/intellij-idea-with-junit-4-7-junit-version-3-8-or-later-expected) post, but I still get the error:

```
!!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.<init>(BaseTestRunner.java:5)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:54)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:48)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:41)

Process finished with exit code -3
```

Not sure what to do from here. Tried reorganizing the order of the Junit dependency. No luck, anyone else get this issue?

Android Studio V. 1.2.1.1

Comment: Hey did you find the solution to this problem? i facing it too.

Comment: I could solve it by removing `unitTest.returnDefaultValues`, check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44820309/965569

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Solved the issue. I was running the JUnit tests as a standard "JUnit test" in `Android Studio`. I fixed the issue by resetting the configuration as a `Android Test`.

Comment: This worked for me but it took a bit to work out how to create an `Android Test`. Go to `Edit Configurations`, select `Android Tests` from the menu on the left, click `+`, and fill in the details on the right.

Comment: if you want to run your test as a standard Junit test be sure your build variant in android studio is set to Unit Tests and then create a Junit test configuration.

Answer (score 29):

Just to add one more situation. I was having this error after updating Android Studio to 4.1 on a project using old AGP (3.3.2) and Gradle (4.10.2). What ended up solving the issue for me was removing the `android.test.runner` library from gradle dependencies, that is removing the following line from the app's module `build.gradle`:

```
useLibrary 'android.test.runner'
```

I probably got lucky to not actually need any of the classes provided by the library for unit or instrumented tests.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me as well. Thank you!

Comment: That also worked for me after updating to Android Studio 4.1!
Thank you so much for posting this! You saved me a few hours of debugging. Cheers

Comment: Fixed it for me for Android Studio 4.1 too! Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Fixed it on Android Studio 4.1

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me - thank you!

Comment: Also had to remove `useLibrary 'android.test.base'` and `useLibrary 'android.test.mock'` - thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I solve this problem by moving "testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'" to the first order in build.gradle dependency block

Answer (score 7):

If you have updated android studio version to 4.1 wiuth latest gradle plygin. Please comment out

// useLibrary 'android.test.runner'
It will fix error for you.

Answer (score 7):

This is apparently an Android Studio 4.1 issue. There's an open ticket for that already: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170328018

What really solved the issue for me was reinstalling the Android 11 (API 30) SDK, according to the bug ticket above:

> "...there was an issue with API 30 mock jar that was built
> incorrectly. Can you open Android Studio SDK Manager and try
> uninstalling the R SDK or any Android SDK Platform 30 please? The
> Gradle build will auto install it when you try to rebuild after you
> delete the R SDK."

Answer (score 5):

Running into this when opening an old project into latest Android Studio 2.3 after it auto-updated the project.

Android Studio supports "Android JUnit" tests which should run using the current host JRE and properly support JUnit 4+. The error is due to the wrong JRE being used.

Solved by using Edit Configuration > select the Android JUnit configuration > edit the JRE. Select any choice, use Apply, then change it back to "Default (Android Platform)" for it work.

Answer (score 5):

The below fix is a work around and a repetitive task you need to perform on every new class that you create. I have used Gradle for my project on Android Studio.

Step 1:
Go to Run-> Edit Configurations
[Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEvZp.png)

Step 2:
For each JUnit test configuration, change and add the below into the fields:
a) JRE: Default is selected. Change it to the JRE version you have on your PC which you get as an option in the drop-down. As of today, its 1.8
b) Before launch field: Click on '+', select your module and add task as "clean compileTestJava". Move it to top in the list
[JUnit test configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MymwA.png)

Step 3: Apply Changes and now run your java class.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue,  I set "JRE" to "1.8". This is Under "Edit Configurations"

Comment: This worked for me, when using Robolectric for unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same error and I fixed it by updating JRE value under "Edit Configurations..." in Android Studio, I used API 28 instead and then it worked. Please check the image for your reference...

[image]

Comment: you, sir, are a scholar and a gentleman!!  thank you - your fixed worked.

Comment: I'm glad it did, best regards!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just forgot that I've changed the build variant to "release". Switching back to "debug" fixed everything. FML.

Answer (score 1):

Running an "Android JUNit" config and having JUnit 4.12 in gradle did not help to resolve this.

I needed to select `JRE` to `Android API 27 Platform` in the run config manually instead of "Default" to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had to update a Gradle settings file according to [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests). I just added the line

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

to the `dependencies` block of my app's `build.gradle` file. If you check the "Project" tab in Android studio (where you can see your source code files) there should be a "Gradle Scripts" section. Look for the `build.gradle` file named after your package and add that line to the `dependencies` block, then click the "Sync now" prompt that should come up.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting similar error when I added new project to workspace. May be they(new Project) would have upgraded Junit version or manadated that project should always use specific version.

In this cases, I closed project(all) along with original workspace and opened in new one.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it with simply editing the project's app.iml and moving order entry after  from bottom:

`<orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="TEST" name="junit-4.12" level="project" />`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the import,
it should be :

```
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
```