# Error JUnit version 3.8 or later expected - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit

Connecting library `JUnit`, when I runing the test, I have a error:

```
!!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! at
    junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.(BaseTestRunner.java:5) at
    junit.textui.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:54) at
    junit.textui.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:48) at
    junit.textui.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:41) at
    com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.junitVersionChecks(JUnitStarter.java:191)
    at
    com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.canWorkWithJUnitVersion(JUnitStarter.java:174)
    at
    com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at
    com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but does your Test `extends TestCase`?

Comment: Have you checked this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629314/android-studio-with-junit-4-12-junit-version-3-8-or-later-expected ?

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/2422378/95725

Comment: I could solve it by removing `unitTest.returnDefaultValues`, check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44820309/965569

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, why didn't you try

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:3.8'
```

?

Comment: Seems like a viable option

Comment: I try 3.8 , 4.11, and other version. the same error

Comment: After changing the file did you sync with gradle, i.e. clean project setup? And if this will not work, try invalidating caches and restart the IDE.

Comment: Yes, after every changing in junit version I cleaning the project

Comment: Did you also invalidate caches of your IDE?