# Android Studio Junit version 3.8 or later expected (even if it's 4+)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

When I try to do some code coverage tests it returns this error. Even if it is higher than 3.8 .

There are some solutions for eclipse or the others but I couldn't find any to Android Studio . Is there any way to do this in Android Studio ?

There is a solution but in my case the libraries are not moving and there is no such library named 'Android 1.6 Platform' or something like that .

Comment: Can you post your error log?

Comment: This question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422378/intellij-idea-with-junit-4-7-junit-version-3-8-or-later-expected

Comment: This doesn't work or I couldn't get done . I can see the libraries but they are not moving .